# What are proofs of the consistency of the propositional calculus?

Tags: lo.logic

Consider the propositional calculus. For specificity I will use the sequent propositional calculus PK as developed in Cook and Nguyen's Logical Foundations of Proof Complexity (for precision the axioms are $\bot \rightarrow$, $\rightarrow \top$, and $A \rightarrow A$ where $A$ is atomic). In order to prove consistency, it suffices to prove that PK does not prove the empty sequent **e**, i.e the sequent with no formulas on either side. Here are four proofs.

FIRST PROOF

All axioms are valid, and every rule of inference preserves validity. But **e** is not valid.

SECOND PROOF

Let $\sigma$ be any particular assignment (e.g. the assignment which maps every letter to $\top$). It satisfies any sequent which is an axiom, and every rule of inference preserves satisfaction by $\sigma$, i.e. if every sequent in the top is satisfied by $\sigma$, then the bottom sequent is also so satisfied. So every sequent in a proof must be satisfied by $\sigma$. But **e** is not satisfied by any assignment and so in particular it is not satisfied by $\sigma$.

THIRD PROOF

Every sequent with a proof has a cut-free proof. All cut-free inferences have a bottom sequent with at least one formula (or, in the case of Exchange, provided the top formula also has at least one formula). All axioms have at least one formula, while **e** has no formula. Therefore there is no cut-free proof of **e**, and thus  **e** cannot be proved.

FOURTH PROOF

Define *simplifies* as follows. $\phi_1$ simplifies $\phi_2$ if $\phi_1$ is the result of substituting the left-hand in the following table  for one instance of the right-hand in $\phi_2$:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
\bot \quad ¬ \top \newline
\top \quad ¬ \bot \newline
\top \quad \top \lor \phi \enspace or \enspace \phi \lor \top \newline
\phi \quad \bot \lor \phi \enspace or \enspace \phi \lor \bot \newline
\bot \quad \bot \land \phi \enspace or \enspace \phi \land \bot \newline
\phi \quad \top \land \phi \enspace or \enspace \phi \land \top \newline
\end{array}$$

Define  a function $^{CS}$ on formulas: $\phi^{CS} = \psi$ if there exists a sequence $\phi = \phi_1,\phi_2,...,\phi_n = \psi$ such that $\phi_{i+1}$ simplifies $\phi_i$ and no formula simplifies $\phi_n$. Intuitively, $\phi^{CS}$ evaluates all constants of $\phi$.  For instance, $((A \lor \top) \land (¬ B \lor \bot))^{CS} = ¬B$.

Note $\top^{CS} = \top$ and $\bot^{CS} = \bot$. Also note if $\phi$ only contains constants, then $\phi^{CS}$ must be a constant, i.e. $\top$ or $\bot$.

Lemma 1.

1. $(¬\phi)^{CS} = \top$ if and only if $(\phi)^{CS} = \bot$
2. $(¬\phi)^{CS} = \bot$ if and only if $(\phi)^{CS} = \top$
3. $(\phi_1 \lor \phi_2)^{CS} = \top$ if and only if $(\phi_1)^{CS} = \top$ or $(\phi_2)^{CS} = \top$
4. $(\phi_1 \lor \phi_2)^{CS} = \bot$ if and only if $(\phi_1)^{CS} = \bot$ and $(\phi_2)^{CS} = \bot$
5. $(\phi_1 \land \phi_2)^{CS} = \top$ if and only if $(\phi_1)^{CS} = \top$ and $(\phi_2)^{CS} = \top$
6. $(\phi_1 \land \phi_2)^{CS} = \bot$ if and only if $(\phi_1)^{CS} = \bot$ or $(\phi_2)^{CS} = \bot$
   //

Lemma 2. If there is a proof of $\Gamma \rightarrow \Delta,\phi$ with $\phi^{CS} = \bot$ or $\Gamma, \phi \rightarrow \Delta$ with $\phi^{CS} = \top$, then there is a shorter proof of $\Gamma \rightarrow \Delta$.

Pf:
Proceed by Induction on the length of the proof.
If $\Gamma \rightarrow \Delta,\phi$ with $\phi^{CS} = \bot$ is an axiom, then it must be of the form $\bot \rightarrow \bot$. But there is a shorter proof of $\bot \rightarrow$, since this is also an axiom. Similarly for $\Gamma, \phi \rightarrow \Delta$ with $\phi^{CS} = \top$.

Now suppose there is a proof of $\Gamma \rightarrow \Delta,\phi$ with $\phi^{CS} = \bot$, and the last step is justified by some inference.

Case 1.  $\Gamma \rightarrow \Delta,\phi$ is inferred from $\Gamma \rightarrow \Delta, \phi,\phi$ via Contraction. Then by the Induction Hypothesis, since $\phi^{CS} = \bot$, there is a shorter proof of $\Gamma \rightarrow \Delta,\phi$. And so by the Induction Hypothesis again there is a shorter proof of $\Gamma \rightarrow \Delta$.

Case 2. $\phi$ is $(\phi_1 \lor \phi_2)$ and $\Gamma \rightarrow \Delta,\phi$ is inferred from $\Gamma \rightarrow \Delta,\phi_1,\phi_2$ via Right $\lor$ Introduction. By Lemma 1(4), $(\phi_1)^{CS} = \bot$ and $(\phi_2)^{CS} = \bot$. But then by the Induction Hypothesis, there is a shorter proof of $\Gamma \rightarrow \Delta, \phi_1$, and by the Induction Hypothesis a second time, there is a shorter proof still of $\Gamma \rightarrow \Delta$.

etc. //

Prop.  PK is consistent.

Pf:
Suppose there is a proof of **e**.  WLOG one may assume it to be a shortest proof. In this proof replace every letter by $\top$.  It remains a shortest proof of **e**. The last step in the new proof must be a cut, with the inference of **e** from (1) $\rightarrow \phi$ and (2)$\phi \rightarrow$.  Since $\phi$ only contains constants, by the note $\phi^{CS} = \top$ or $\phi^{CS} = \bot$. By Lemma 2 there is a shorter proof of **e**, a contradiction. Therefore there is no proof of **e**. //

**What are other essentially different proofs of the consistency of the propositional calculus?**

Comment: When you have a proof as simple and natural as FIRST PROOF, what's the motivation for wanting others?

Comment: I don’t think the 1st and 2nd proof are the same. In particular, the 1st proof requires induction for a formula of higher complexity than the 2nd proof, as propositional validity is coNP-complete, whereas evaluation of formulas under a fixed assignment is $\mathrm{NC^1}$. Consequently, formalization of the 1st proof requires the theory $V^1$ (or $S^1_2$ in the one-sorted setup), whereas the 2nd proof can be formalized in the weaker theory $\mathit{VNC^1}$ (this is in fact done in Cook and Nguyen’s book).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek.  Happy to retract the "essentially the same."  Thanks.  I'll edit.

Comment: @AlexKruckman. For one thing, the first proof is semantic, while the third and fourth are syntactic. That usually has an interest. Also, as Emil pointed out, other proofs may be formalizable in weaker theories than the first proof.